# Weird @font-face rendering in Chrome

Tags: css, font-face, font-family

as mentioned - I have an issue with font rendering, but only in one place on the website (the font is used also for other classes, but seems to work fine everywhere else). I have a Wordpress website, and first position in menu renders absolutely mental:

[image]

I already changed all the files for this particular font, tried commenting out only the svg declaration, also added -webkit-text-stroke: 1px transparent; but despite all these, the problem still occurs (only on the first load though; after refreshing, it shows 'Homepage').

Please find the CSS declaration for this class below:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'GothamRounded-Medium';
    src: url('fonts/GothamRounded-Medium.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-    opentype'),  
    url('fonts/GothamRounded-Medium.otf')  format('opentype'),
    url('fonts/GothamRounded-Medium.woff') format('woff'), 
    url('fonts/GothamRounded-Medium.ttf')  format('truetype'),
    url('fonts/GothamRounded-Medium.svg#GothamRounded-Medium') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

#main-nav li {
    font-family: 'GothamRounded-Medium', sans-serif, arial;
    font-size:15px;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #063F77;
    background:#004a8d;
}
```

I'll be grateful for any hints.

Thanks,
E.

E: While trying other font kits, one of these renders all the characters, but with unnatural letter spacing. I tried declaring default letter-spacing value, but it's not helpful as well. Please find the image attached below:

[image]

Not sure if it actually adds anything to the topic, but it seems to hate only this one particular menu position. I tried changing the word to something else and the problem still occurs (apparently the word 'carrot' looks even funnier). I also tried to adding the menu position one more time - no change.

Comment: @BenM It should say 'Homepage'. Also - the language is set to en-GB.

Comment: Is it live so that we can check?

Comment: @Nick I do realize how troublesome it is, however without client's approval I cannot provide the staging link.

Comment: ok i understand. Any error in the console?

Comment: @Nick No, everything is fine. Just tried testing different fonts. With system fonts everything is rendered properly. Once I use any font-face set, the problem occurs again.

Comment: and again, only on "homepage" and only on the first load, correct?

Comment: Yes. I just updated a question with another image illustrating the problem.

Comment: Are there any other classes/styles being applied to the first link in the menu that aren't being applied to the other links?

Comment: No. Everything is exactly the same. The latest Internet Explorer seems to be picking up some legacy issues for this particular font kit, however in IE the font is displayed properly... Just an off-topic notice unrelated with previous comment.